# Rails association new_path error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models post and topic in my rails app

```html
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  #relation between topics and post
  belongs_to :topic

  #post is valid only if it's associated with a topic:

   validates :topic_id, :presence => true
  #can also require that the referenced topic itself be valid
  #in order for the post to be valid:

  validates_associated :topic



end
```

And

```html
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  #relation between topics and post
  has_many :posts
end
```

I am trying to create association between both of them.

I want multiple post corresponding to each topic

I have used nested routes

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  # nested routes
  resources :topics do
    resources :posts
  end

      resources :userdetails


  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

My Post controller looks like

```html
class PostsController < ApplicationController
 # before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  before_filter :has_userdetail_and_topic, :only =>[:new, :create]



  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json

  #for new association SAAS book

  protected
  def has_userdetail_and_topic

    unless(@topic =Topic.find_by_id(params[:topic_id]))
      flash[:warning] = 'post must be for an existing topic'
    end
  end

  public

  def new
    @post = @topic.posts.build
    #@@topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id1])

  end

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new


  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create



    #@topic.posts << @post
    #@current_user = current_user.id
    @current_user.posts << @topic.posts.build(params[:post])
    #@post = Post.new(post_params )

    #@post.userdetail_id = current_user.id

     #Association functional between topic and post
     #Class variable used
     #@@topic.posts << @post

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:topic_id,:issue, :description, :rating, :userdetail_id)
    end
end
```

I am trying to navigate from topics/index via code `<td><%= link_to 'Write', new_topic_post_path(@topic) %>     </td>`

but when i try to go at `localhost:3000/topics]`
I am getting error

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"posts", :topic_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:topic_id]
```

Can any body tell me about this error, as i am new to rails please clearly specify answer.
And I have one more doubt, please tell me if i am doing association between topic and post incorrectly.I have confusion about this line of code -

```
@topic.posts << @post
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the error `missing required keys: [:topic_id]` is telling you is that you need to provide a hash with the key `topic_id`:

```
<%= link_to 'Write', new_topic_post_path(topic_id: @topic) %>
```

Passing a resource as to a route helper only works for the `id` param:

```
<%= link_to @topic, topic_path(@topic) %>
```

Is a kind of shorthand for:

```
<%= link_to @topic, topic_path(id: @topic.to_param) %>
```

### Addition:

@prcu is also correct. The `@topic` record needs to be saved to the database. Records which are not saved do not have an id since the database assigns the id column when the record is inserted.

You also need to set the `@topic` instance variable in PostsController:

```
@topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
```

This is commonly done with a before filter:

```
before_filter :set_topic, only: [:new]  

def set_topic
   @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
end
```

The same also need to be done in `TopicsController#index`.

Comment: `new_topic_post_path(topic_id: @topic)`

Comment: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClas now this error

Comment: Edited answer. The error is because you have not defined @topic in TopicsController#index. If you need more help add the contents of TopicsController and `views/topics/index.html.erb`

Comment: i have solved that problem but getting new error undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass in def new
    @post = @topic.posts.build
    

  end

Comment: Little offtop. Just notice about before filters: helper method is a better approach. Just use `def topic; @topic ||= Topic.find params[:id]; end` and define `helper_method :topic`. It'll save your time if you have a lot of actions or filters in controller. You can read `inherited_resources` gem's source for examples, it uses same method.

Comment: Not sure if I agree - I like having better control over what query gets fired where. Such as doing a `Topic->Post` join instead in a before_filter when you are using both. But thats really offtopic.

Comment: Yes u are right @papirtiger it is really time saving

Comment: getting error in controller undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass in  @current_user.posts << @topic.posts.build(params[:post]) .i have edited controller.

Comment: @user3841197 please ask a new question - don´t edit and ask in comments.

Answer (score 1):

`@topic` is not set or it's not persisted. You can not use `topic` not saved to db in this helper.